# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /srv/disk1/1185368/www/mashcraft.atwebpages.com/profile.php on line 76

Tags: php, sql

please help whats wrong with this code?
(line 76 is the middle one)

```
require("dbConfig.php");
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM dbUsers WHERE username='$_SESSION["valid_user"]'';
$r = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Why do you use the `mysql` extension? It's deprecated; you should use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead! Also, consider storing the user id instead of the username in the session.

Answer (score 2):

Please concate your string

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM dbUsers WHERE username="'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["valid_user"]).'"';
```

Recommendations:

1.Learn to prevent from MySQL Injections: [Good Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

2.Mysql extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. More reading: [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Answer (score 0):

you missed `.` in:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM dbUsers WHERE username='$_SESSION["valid_user"]'';
```

should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbUsers WHERE username='".$_SESSION["valid_user"]."'";
```

Comment: Ugh, I'd really use double quotes for the outer string. Escaping quotes is rather ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM dbUsers WHERE username='.$_SESSION["valid_user"];
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS (you`ll prevent SQL injection if you sanitize user input):

```
<?php
require("dbConfig.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbUsers WHERE username='".filter_var(mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["valid_user"]),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)."'";
$r = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

EDIT: Added mysql_real_escape_string() for escaping input string, however even this is not 100% efficient against SQL injection, as discussed [here](http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html).

Comment: That's a **horrible suggestion**. You **MUST** use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to properly escape a string for using in a MySQL query.